# Annotating Kubernetes resource with expiry time

Tags: kubernetes, annotations

I want to add Annotation as expiry time in a Kubernetes resource (rbac definition object).

How to add annotation as the expiry time.

Pseudo code is something like below,

```yaml
 annotations:
   expiry-time: {{ current date + 1 hour }}
```

How to add this custom annotation? What's the language of code needs to be added for custom annotation?

Comment: How are you otherwise creating the object?  What difficulty have you run into writing it out in essentially the form you have in the question?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using *nix shell like bash you can use the [`date`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) command  and the [`kubectl patch`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/) command .

```sh
kubectl patch <k8s-resource> <resource-name> -p \
 "{\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"expiry-time\":\"`date -d '1 hour' '+%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S'`\"}}}"
```

If you are on Mac you can substitute the `date` command with this:

```sh
date -v+1d '+%m/%d/%Y -%H:%M:%S'
```

✌️☮️

Comment: I got  error,                                                                                                                   kubectl patch rbacdefinition joe-access -p \
 "{\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"expiry-time\":\"`date -d '1 hour' '+%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S'`\"}}}"
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
Error from server (UnsupportedMediaType): the body of the request was in an unknown format - accepted media types include: application/json-patch+json, application/merge-patch+json

Comment: check if this run `date -d '1 hour' '+%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S'`. you may have a different variation of the date command

Comment: oh you are probably running from a mac

Comment: on a mac `date -v+1d '+%m/%d/%Y -%H:%M:%S'`

Comment: Thankyou..this command works in mac..However I am still getting below error,kubectl patch rbacdefinition joe-access -p \
 "{\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"expiry-time\":\"`date -v+1H  '+%m%d/%Y -%H:%M:%S'`\"}}}"
Error from server (UnsupportedMediaType): the body of the request was in an unknown format - accepted media types include: application/json-patch+json, application/merge-patch+json

Comment: what resource is `rbacdefinition`?  Does that support annotations?

Comment: yes..that supports annotation..I checked in the rbac-manager slack channel..Its a CRD

Comment: Ok..I tried this and it worked..kubectl patch  rbacdefinition joe-access --patch "$(cat rbac-merge.json)" --type=merge
rbacdefinition.rbacmanager.reactiveops.io/joe-access patched

Comment: However in the definition,I still see the raw date command but not the result of it  metadata:
    annotations:
      expiry-time: '`date -v+1H  ''+%m%d/%Y -%H:%M:%S''`'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218534/discussion-between-rad4-and-rico).

Answer (score 0):

This worked..

```
 kubectl annotate rbacdefinition  joe-access "expires-at=$(date -v+1H  '+%m%d/%Y -%H:%M:%S')"
```